# ExecuteMultipleResponse; How to read and store Guids from the response

Tags: c#, list, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I am using ExecuteMultipleResponse method to insert 10 account records at a time using SSIS.

```
    List<Entity> _Accounts = new List<Entity>();
//  Check the batch size and process
public override void InputAccount_ProcessInput(InputAccountBuffer Buffer)
{
    //List<int> personIDs = new List<int>();

    int index = 0;


    while (Buffer.NextRow())
    {
        _Accounts.Add(InputAccountFromBuffer(Buffer));
        //personIDs.Add(int.Parse(Buffer.sPersonID));
        index++;

        if (index == 10)
        {
            ImportBatch();
            index = 0;
        }
    }
    ImportBatch();
}

private void ImportBatch()
{
    if (_Accounts.Count > 0)
    {
        var multipleRequest = new ExecuteMultipleRequest()
        {
            Settings = new ExecuteMultipleSettings()
            {
                ContinueOnError = true,
                ReturnResponses = true
            },
            Requests = new OrganizationRequestCollection()
        };

        foreach (var profContact in _Accounts)
        {
            CreateRequest reqCreate = new CreateRequest();
            reqCreate.Target = profContact;
            reqCreate.Parameters.Add("SuppressDuplicateDetection", false);
            multipleRequest.Requests.Add(reqCreate);
        }

        ExecuteMultipleResponse multipleResponses = (ExecuteMultipleResponse)organizationservice.Execute(multipleRequest);

        var responses = (ExecuteMultipleResponseItemCollection)multipleResponses.Results["Responses"];

        foreach (var response in responses)
            {
                if (response.Fault != null)
                    {
                    // A fault has occurred, handle it here
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       // THIS IS WHERE I KNOW THE GUID VALUE EXIST.
                    }
            }


        //IEnumerator f = multipleResponses.Responses.GetEnumerator();


        _Accounts.Clear();
    }

}
```

Above code is working fine, however, I now need to read and store Guids from response to a List. This information is essential for the next step in the package. I know, if I am creating single record I can simply say,

```
Guid newRecord = _service.Create(account);
```

I even managed to get down to check if the response have 'Fault' or not and if it doesn't have fault then Guid value should exist in the response.

Running response.Response.Results.Values in QuickWatch shows me the guid but I just can't find a way to read it directly and store it as a Guid.
[image]

Comment: Thank you Guido, but I can't get to the guid value in first place. So how can I store it in Array. I know the response itself is Array of 10 records at a time but when I try, Response.Results.Values.Item[0], I get error that item doesn't exist

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to link the data passed into `ExecuteRequest` to the Guid that's returned in the Responses. Is it such that the element at the `[0]` element of the Responses corresponds to the `[0]` element of the original multiple request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The guid of a created record should be stored in the `OrganizationResponse` which can be found inside the `ExecuteMultipleResponseItem`
Try the following to get the guid as a string:

```
string id = response.Response.Results["id"].ToString()
```

If it works as expected you should also be able to instantiate a guid, if needed:

```
Guid guid = new Guid(id);
```

Comment: That worked! You are a genius sir. Thank you so much @Henrik, after three hours of banging my head on my desk I can finally see the Guid. All thanks to you. :)

Comment: Is `"id"` the only thing returned by the `Results` prop, or does it return other values used to create the record?

I'm hoping for a way to tie each of the Responses back to its specific Request - hoping to use values sent in the Request in the first place.